# Trouble figuring out logic for while/if loop in C

Tags: c, if-statement, logic, do-while

I have a some code, and the function I am having trouble with is this:

```
unsigned int getInputData() {

    printf("Please input a positive integer number terminated with a carriage return.\n");

    do{ 
        scanf("%c", &input);

        if(isdigit(input))  {
            temp = charToInt(input);
            rValue = mergeInt(rValue, temp);
        }
        if(rValue >= imax)  {
            rValue = 0;
            printf("ERROR: That is too large of an integer. Please try again. \n");
        }
        else if(isalpha(input)){
            rValue = 0;
            printf("This is not a integer. Please try again. \n");
        }
        else{
            printf("OK. This is a good number. \n");
        }
    } while(1);
}
```

I'm scanning in each `char` individually, merging it into an `int`. Which is exactly what I want to do BUT I only want it to print `"OK. This is a good number."` once when the user types it in. Example: If someone was to type in: `12345` I want it to return: `"OK. This is a good number."` once for those 5 char rather than once each. Hoping this makes sense, been at it for awhile so anything will help.

Comment: Why are you using global variables `input`, `imax`, `rValue` and `temp`?  Or why are you deleting your variable definitions before posting the code?  You must error check `scanf()`; otherwise, you'll never know when you hit EOF.  It appears that you can type `123@` or `123.` etc and the number is OK, but if you type `123a` it is not.  What characters do you really want to terminate the number?  You're right that `scanf()` does not (necessarily) protect itself from overflow.  Should you push back the character that ends the number?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry about that I'll add in the variable definitions (though I don't believe they're all that necessary). This is just a 'quick' piece of code so I'm not really worried about any overflows or anything like that. Would just like the print statement to behave the way I would like it too.

Comment: Your validation `if (rValue > imax)` should probably be in the `if (isdigit(input))` code block; there's no point in testing for overflow if you've not attempted to set `rValue`. It also affects your logic that is your principal problem.  When you find a good number, you should exit the `do { … } while (1);` loop.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler how do I go about exiting the `do-while loop` while still checking each `char` individually?

Comment: You've got a pretty decent answer; mine was going to be similar in some ways, and different too. On the whole, I like the other solution better than mine, though mine is closer to your original code in at least some respects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's huge logic problems behind your code:

- You loop infinitely without checking for end of input:

You say you want to tell whether this is a good number when the user inputs several digits, but you do only read one character at a time, and you do not define how a number ends.
Though you do specify to end with a carriage return, you did not design your algorithm that way, you never check for the `\n` character.

- You define a return value for the `getInputData()` function but you do never return from that function.
- You test whether `input` is a digit to update the value, but for errors you do show an error only if it's an alphabetic character.

Basically, to keep with the way you wrote your algorithm, here's another take:

```
unsigned int getInputData() {
    char input;
    long value=0;

    do {
        scanf("%c", &input);

        if (isdigit(input))
            value = value*10+input+'0';
        else if (input == '\n')
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;

    } while(1);
}

int main() {
    printf("Please input a positive integer number terminated with a carriage return.\n");

    if (getInputData() == 1)
        printf("OK. This is a good number.\n");
    else
        printf("This is not a integer. Please try again. \n");

    return 0;
}
```

but I do exit from the infinite loop to be able to check the result.

*N.B.*: for the purpose of the example, I did not check for overflows.
*N.B.1*: I kept using [`scanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) to stay close to your code, but if you only want to read one character at a time, it is better to use [`getchar()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getc.3.html) which is way simpler and faster. 
*N.B.2*: you can also simplify your code by using more features of [`scanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html):

```
unsigned int getInputData() {
    unsigned input;
    long value=0;
    int n;

    do {
        n = scanf("%u", &input);
        if (n == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
    } while(1);
}
```

You may even try to use `scanf("%a[0-9]")` which is a GNU extension. See [`man scanf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) for more details.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would you loop this until the user enters the proper int?

Comment: basically: `while (getInputData() != 1) { printf("This is not an integer, please try again.\n"); } printf("Good boy. This is an integer.");`… Actually that's kind of obvious, why this question?